# Django get_absolute_url for ManyToManyField

Tags: django, url, django-models, many-to-many

I am trying to set up a site for the url flow to be:
states -> county -> storename

With ForeignKey between county and state I was able to use get_absolute_url with something like:

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('county-detail', args=[str(self.states),str(self.county)
```

I am now trying to create my model for storename and am having problems with manytomany relationships. I tried making states and county foreign keys within the model and it works with get_absolute_url. However, storenames can be in multiple states and counties.

My current model code is:

```
class StoreName(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
county = models.ManyToManyField('county')
states = models.ManyToManyField('states')

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('StoreName-detail', args=[str(self.states),str(self.county),str(self.name)])
```

I am getting the error:
'Reverse for 'StoreName-detail' with arguments '('ls.states.None', 'ls.county.None', 'Ralphs')' not found'

Is there a way to have states and county populate data for the args like it did when they were foreignkeys?

When I hard coded an example for args it works such as:

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('StoreName-detail', args=['California','Los-Angeles',str(self.name)])
```

Comment: Here `self.states` is a `ManyToManyField`, so that makes no much sense: there can be zero, one or more states. What if a `StoreName` has three states, what would the `absolute_url` look like?

Comment: Can I pull based on the url the link is on?  So if the user is on page: site/california/los-angeles/  then the arguments given are: California for states and Los Angeles for county. Would become: site/california/los-angeles/ralphs.

If the user was on site/california/san-diego/  the url path would be site/california/san-diego/ralphs

Comment: that would *not* be a good idea, since `get_absolute_url` should be a *canonical URL*: it means that these should be unique per store, but not unique *per user* per store, especially since it is not said that there is a logged in user, and furthermore models are *request-unaware*.

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem thank you so much for helping, I am very new to django. So I can only go backwards?  Ralphs/Los-Angeles/California?
Can I use anything besides get_absolute_url to do what I am looking for?